# SSRS BIDS 2008 Change NaN to 0 and 0%

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, nan

[image]

See above table, is it possible to change all instances of NaN to 0 in the numerical field and 0% in the percentage field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like =IIF(Fields!Days.Value > 0,Fields!Days.Value/Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "Date_month_name"),0)

Comment: Still getting NaN's coming through much to my dismay

Comment: This is correct, but it violates the DRY principle especially when there is a longer calculation involved.